# Avahi dns_sd compatibility layer fails to run Browse callback

Tags: c, bonjour, zeroconf, avahi, dns-sd

#### Background

I'm working on a cross-platform Zeroconf/Bonjour/DNS-SD library for Haskell, and figured my best bet would bet would be to target the [`dns_sd.h`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/dns_sd_h/index.html) API. Under Linux, the implementation of this interface is provided by [Avahi](http://avahi.org/wiki/AboutAvahi), which claims to support a subset of the Bonjour API.

#### Problem

As a sanity check for my library, I've written a small test program in C that just uses the bare bones of the API. It browses for any service on the network of type `_http._tcp`, prints a message as soon as it sees one, and then dies:

```
#include <dns_sd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cb(DNSServiceRef sdRef,
        DNSServiceFlags flags,
        uint32_t interfaceIndex,
        DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,
        const char *serviceName,
        const char *regtype,
        const char *replyDomain,
        void *context) {
  printf("called!\n");
}

int main() {
  DNSServiceRef sd = malloc(sizeof(DNSServiceRef));
  const char *regtype = "_http._tcp";
  DNSServiceErrorType err1 = DNSServiceBrowse(&sd, 0, 0, regtype, NULL, &cb, NULL);
  printf("err1=%d\n", err1);
  DNSServiceErrorType err2 = DNSServiceProcessResult(sd);
  printf("err2=%d\n", err2);
  return 0;
}
```

On my Mac, this test program works fine in both C and the equivalent Haskell (it finds my printer; exciting!):

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test
err1=0
called!
err2=0
```

But on my Linux machine, the program berates me before exiting without invoking the callback:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test -ldns_sd
$ ./test
*** WARNING *** The program 'test' uses the Apple Bonjour compatibility layer of Avahi.
*** WARNING *** Please fix your application to use the native API of Avahi!
*** WARNING *** For more information see <http://0pointer.de/avahi-compat?s=libdns_sd&e=test>
err1=0
err2=0
```

#### Questions

1. Is the Avahi `dns_sd` compatibility layer still a suitable target for a cross-platform binding? Or is that warning message serious enough about using the native Avahi API that I should consider retargeting?
2. What is the state of the art for cross-platform Zeroconf in C?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Avahi, so I can't help you. Just a question: tthe instruction "DNSServiceRef sd = malloc(sizeof(DNSServiceRef));" seems quite strange to me. It seems that DNSServiceRef is a pointer to something (a structure, I suppose), but it's initialised with a pointer to a block of memory of the size of the same pointer... is it correct?

Comment: @Giuseppe Guerrini: yes; I had tried before with just the pointer, and switched to `malloc` in case it made a difference for some weird reason. Both versions worked the same.

Comment: setenv("AVAHI_COMPAT_NOWARN", "1", 0); // disable the annoying warning!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reason unknown to me, it works only with non-blocking calls. Below is the improved code. Socket from Avahi is set to a non-blocking mode and then `select (3)` is used to wait for available data. `DNSServiceProcessResult(sd)` has to be called each time there is data on the socket so it may have been pure luck that your example worked on other platforms.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dns_sd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

static int set_nonblocking(int fd)
{
    int flags;
    /* If they have O_NONBLOCK, use the Posix way to do it */
#if defined(O_NONBLOCK)
    /* Fixme: O_NONBLOCK is defined but broken on SunOS 4.1.x and AIX 3.2.5. */
    if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)))
        flags = 0;
    return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
#else
    /* Otherwise, use the old way of doing it */
    flags = 1;
    return ioctl(fd, FIOBIO, &flags);
#endif
}     

void cb(DNSServiceRef sdRef,
        DNSServiceFlags flags,
        uint32_t interfaceIndex,
        DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,
        const char *serviceName,
        const char *regtype,
        const char *replyDomain,
        void *context) {
    printf("called %s %s!\n", serviceName, regtype);
}

int main() {
    DNSServiceRef sd = malloc(sizeof(DNSServiceRef));
    const char *regtype = "_http._tcp";
    DNSServiceErrorType err1 = DNSServiceBrowse(&sd, 0, 0, regtype, NULL, &cb, NULL);
    printf("err1=%d\n", err1);
    int socket = DNSServiceRefSockFD(sd);
    set_nonblocking(socket);

    fd_set read_fds;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(socket, &read_fds);

    while(1) {
        if(select(socket+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL)  < 0) {
            perror("select");  
        }
        DNSServiceErrorType err2 = DNSServiceProcessResult(sd);
        printf("err2=%d\n", err2);
        if(err2 != 0)
            return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```